# Angular 4 unsubscribe causes an error when navigating

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular4-router

I have recently learnt to avoid memory leak, I need to unsubscribe in my components. To do this I implement `OnDestroy` but this has caused an issue when navigating.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

If I don't unsubscribe navigation completes successfully.

I was under the impression that `ngOnDestroy` only happens once everything else has completed, obviously that is not the case.

I'm obviously doing something really wrong, but I cant figure out what How do I unsubscribe when navigating away from a page?

```
export class PropertyFormMapperComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private _routeSubscription: any;
    private _getPropertySubscription: any;

    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _propertyFormFileService: PropertyFormFileService,
        private _router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._routeSubscription = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this._id = params['id'];
            this._getPropertySubscription = this._propertyService.getProperty(this._id).subscribe(property => {
                ...do stuff...
            });
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this._getPropertySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    private onCreate(event: any): void {    
        this._propertyService.postProperty(property, 1).subscribe(
            response => {
                ...do stuff...
                this._router.navigate(['home']);
            },
            error => {
                ...other stuff...
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you log the values to the console in `ngOnDestroy` to find which one of the two subscriptions is not defined?

Comment: The nested one is not defined - `_getPropertySubscription`. Having subscribe inside another subscribe is a bad rxjs practice and a common mistake beginners do. You should combine the streams using higher order rxjs methods to combine the streams

Comment: You could just check if _subscription_ is defined before invoking `unsubscribe`...

Comment: @codeepic thank you for your advice, what do you mean by `combine the streams using higher order rxjs methods`, following your advice i'm now reviewing http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0 which mentions `concat`, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, `concatMap` to be more specific. Which version of `rxjs` do you use? I hope the later one, so the syntax in my answer works for you --> newer version pipes operator functions and instead of `.do()` uses `.tap()` since `do` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this one should work for you. I combined route params stream and getProperty  stream using `concatMap` and projection function. You can read more about it in rxjs docs: [rxjs concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)

I also use `takeUntil` which unsubscribes from the stream it is piped into when other stream emits. [rxjs takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html)

So when `componentDestroyed$` observable emits, because `takeUntil` took it as a param, `takeUntil` will then unsubscribe from `this._route.params` and `this._propertyService.getProperty` streams.

I also added `takeUntil` to `onCreate` method, since you also subscribe in there.

`takeUntil` is an alternative to keeping track of all your `Subuscription`s and manually unsubscribing from them in `ngOnDestroy`. With `takeUntil` we achieve the same thing, but don't have to clutter the component with subscription properties.

You can take it one step up and have a base class that all your component classes inherit from --> then you don't have to keep `componentDestroyed$` in every component and can skip `ngOnDestroy()` part too:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
    protected componentDestroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentDestroyed$.next();
        this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
    }
}
```

And your components now will be inheriting from `BaseComponent`:

`export class PropertyFormMapperComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy`

Your code fixed:

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {tap, map, concatMap, takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';

export class PropertyFormMapperComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    componentDestroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _propertyFormFileService: PropertyFormFileService,
        private _router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._route.params
            .pipe(
                map(params => params['id']),
                tap(id => this._id = id),
                concatMap(id => this._propertyService.getProperty(id))
                takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$),
                tap(property => {
                   ...do stuff...
                   ... side effects are handled in tap functions     
                })
            )
            .subscribe();        
    }

    private onCreate(event) {    
        this._propertyService.postProperty(property, 1)
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
            )
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    ...do stuff...
                    this._router.navigate(['home']);
                },
                error => {
                    ...other stuff...
                }
            );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentDestroyed$.next();
        this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was  just trying to write a solution based on some really contrived examples. I'm not sure how long it would have taken me. There is so much to learn on rx. Thanks again

Comment: Should the import `import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';` I was under the impression that importing `'rxjs'` would just import the full library?

Comment: Yeah, RxJS is really cool, but it's tough to learn on your own. The docs are hard to understand, the older docs were completely unreadable, so it's still an improvement. ;-D Watch some egghead videos on the topic or frontend-masters.com. angular-university.io has good vids and blog posts too.

Comment: If you import from `rxjs` you will get all, but it's better to only import what's needed.

Comment: one last question...how the hell do i debug it :D? id is always 0. If I use `this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
            var id = params['id'];
         });` id is the expected value

Comment: Because of the asychronous nature of streams, I find ol' `console.log` the best help. So drop in `tap(params => console.log('params are: ', params)),` just above `map(params => params['id']),` to see the whole params object before you start mapping over and doing other operations.